# Sound effects sliders not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, cocos2d-iphone

This doesn't work with my other layers for some reason even though it works well in my option layer. Is there something that I need to put to get this slider to work in my other layers? I use play effect when certain enemies spawn and the sound effect will play. Appreciate any help that I can get.

```
    CCControlSlider *slider1 = [CCControlSlider sliderWithBackgroundFile:@"sound bar2.png" progressFile:@"sound bar2.png" thumbFile:@"sound icon.png"];
    slider1.minimumValue = 0.0f; // Sets the min value of range
    slider1.maximumValue = 1.0f; // Sets the max value of range

    // When the value of the slider will change, the given selector will be call
    [slider1 addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged1:) forControlEvents:CCControlEventValueChanged];

    [slider1 setPosition:ccp(240,8)];        

    [self addChild:slider1 z:1];


- (void)valueChanged1:(CCControlSlider *)sender
{
    // Change volume of your sounds
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:sender.value];
}
```

If you need any more files or have any more questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: inside valueChanged1 add this NSLog(@"sender.value: %f", sender.value); and see if it outputs anything. It may be that the value you are passing across isnt what you are expecting to receive